# Spectral decomposition of a symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

If i have a symmetric matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ it follows from the spectral theorem that we can write $A$ as
\begin{equation}
A=Q\Lambda Q^*=\sum_{i=1}^n \mu_i m_i m_i^*
\end{equation}
with $Q$ unitary and $\Lambda$ diagonal, and where the columns of $Q$ are a set of orthonormal eigenvectors $m_1,...,m_n$ and the diagonal elements of $\Lambda$ the corresponding eigenvalues $\mu_1,...,\mu_n$.

Does the above fact imply that i can decompose $A$ in this way ?
\begin{equation}
A=\sum_{i=1}^n v_i v_i^*
\end{equation}
where $v_1,....,v_n$ is a set of mutually orthogonal eigenvectors corresponding to the Eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: If all the $\mu_i$'s are non-negative, you can just set $v_i = \sqrt{\mu_i}m_i$. If one of the $\mu_i$'s are negative, you will have a problem decomposing $A$ in the manner you seek.